# What do braces surrounding a member variable mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I am wondering what { } in the following. What { } is doing here? $this->{$key} = $value;

Thanks in advance.

In one file

```
$config['field']['calendar'] = array('type'=>'boolean');
$config['field']['category'] = array('type'=>'boolean');
$config['field']['customers'] = array('type'=>'boolean');  
...
$this->preference_form->initalize($config);
```

And in Preference_form.php

```
function initalize($config = array())
{
    foreach($config as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're optional in this case, but it's a way of making it clearer to the reader (and the parser) that you're referring to a variable.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an
>   ambiguity problem. That is, if you write $$a[1] then the parser needs
>   to know if you meant to use $a[1] as a variable, or if you wanted $$a
>   as the variable and then the [1] index from that variable. The syntax
>   for resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1]} for the first case and
>   ${$a}[1] for the second.

Another case where this syntax is useful is when expanding a function call in a string.

This doesn't work (or rather it'll evaluate `$someObj` as a string, and then append `->someFunc()`:

```
$myString = "$someObj->someFunc()";
```

But this does what you'd expect:

```
$myString = "{$someObj->someFunc()}";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's escaping the variable expression so that the member can be set dynamically.

Take a look at the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: So it's basically, a glorified `eval`? Shouldn't an array be used for this as is done in the first block of code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by glorified eval, to be honest. The loop is a reasonable pattern in this case.